# About e-mail format validation in laravel project

Tags: laravel

I want to implement a server-side email address validation in the laravel project. How I can solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

in your controller the function that get request, adding the validation like example:

```
public function yourFunction(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'email',
    ]);
// add other code
}
```

remember the validate must be at the top of function.

for more information about the validation in laravel open [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation)

Comment: what you mean about domain server?

Comment: means verify mail server validation like example@gmail.com and example@outlook.com with specific domain like @gmail.com